# Vuex and vue-property-decorator reactivity with $store

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-component, reactive-programming, vuex

i'm trying to use vuex $store on my @Component. But its not be reactive :/

Exemple :

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component
  export default class Internationalize extends Vue {

    protected selectedLanguage: any = this.$store.getters['globalLocale'];

    private langages = this.$store.getters['globalLanguages'];

    protected switchLanguage(locale: any) {
      if (locale !== this.selectedLanguage.locale) {
        const newLanguage = this.langages.find((lang: any) => lang.locale === locale);
        this.$store.dispatch('updateLocale', newLanguage);
      }
    }
  }
```

`this.$store.dispatch('updateLocale', newLanguage);` 
The state `globalLanguages` will be changed but my variable `selectedLanguage` isn't reactive..

Thanks

**EDIT : WORK GREAT**

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

  @Component({
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        selectedLanguage: 'globalLocale',
        langages: 'globalLanguages'
      })
    }
  })
  export default class Internationalize extends Vue {

    protected selectedLanguage!: any;
    protected langages!: any;

    protected flag = this.$store.getters.globalLocale.flagSuffix;

    protected switchLanguage(locale: any) {
      if (locale !== this.selectedLanguage.locale) {
        const newLanguage = this.langages.find((lang: any) => lang.locale === locale);
        this.$store.dispatch('updateLocale', newLanguage).then(() => {
          this.$i18n.locale = locale;
          this.$i18n.setLocaleMessage(this.$i18n.locale, this.$store.getters.globalTranslations);
          this.$i18n.fallbackLocale = process.env.VUE_APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console

Comment: OP has posted the same question in GitHub issues: https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/issues/195

Comment: @erb thanks, it's me on this issues 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `selectedLanguage` is not a computed property/getter, so it's value is only assigned when the class is instantiated, and not when the store's `globalLocale` is updated later.

The first solution is to simply covert your `selectedLanguage` into a computed property (aka getter) in the component itself:

```
protected get selectedLanguage() {
    return this.$store.getters['globalLocale'];
}
```

Alternatively, you can also [use `mapGetters` in the `@Component` decorator instead](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/109#issuecomment-310919020):

```
@Component({
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            selectedLanguage: 'globalLocale'
        })
    }
})
```

However, the problem with this is that you lose type safety in the second solution, and you will have to declare the type returned for `selectedLanguage`, if you wish, in the component itself, i.e.:

```
@Component({
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            selectedLanguage: 'globalLocale'
        })
    }
})
export default class Internationalize extends Vue {
    protected selectedLanguage!: <YourTypeHere>
}
```